# mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `inventory` WHERE `owner` = $user[id] AND `dressed` = '0' AND name = '$kk' AND koll >= $vv"), 0, 0);

Tags: php, php7

```
$db->result($db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `inventory` WHERE `owner` = $user[id] AND `dressed` = '0' AND name = '$kk' AND koll >= $vv"), 0, 0);
$db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `inventory` WHERE `owner` = $user[id] AND `dressed` = '0' AND name = '$kk' AND koll >= $vv"), 0, 0 $db->result();
```

Comment: какой из этих правильный?

Comment: ни один. Т.к. расширение mysql_ устарело тысячелетие назад. А подставлять переменные непосредственно в запрос - большое зло